# Перекрестное сравнение

Tags: python

Всем, привет! Имеем два столбца, берем данные из первой стройки второй столбец novosibirskaya-53, ищем совпадение с первым столбцом находим два результат, берем данные из первой строки столбце 1 и находим совпадение, нашли одно совпадение и эту строку удаляем. Как описать такую функцию?

```
frunze-9_2      novosibirskaya-53
frunze-9_2      frunze-9
novosibirskaya-53   frunze-9_2
novosibirskaya-53   frunze-67
frunze-9        frunze-9_2
frunze-9        uzl-pr-6
frunze-67           novosibirskaya-53
```

Должны получить:

```
frunze-9_2         novosibirskaya-53
frunze-9_2         frunze-9
novosibirskaya-53  frunze-67
frunze-9           uzl-pr-6
```

Comment: хм... что же вы так объясняете-то не понятно))) хорошо хоть пример привели - ясно стало что вы хотите

я бы сделал примерно следующее:

arr = [
    ['a', 'b'],
    ['b', 'c'],
    ['c', 'a'],
    ['b', 'a']
]

result = dict()
for record in arr:
    from_city = record[0]
    to_city = record[1]
    if to_city in result and result[to_city] == from_city:
        continue
    result[from_city] = to_city

print result

алгоритм думаю ясен, остальное переделаете под себя)

Comment: В это коде уникальность присутствует, если ключи будут дублироваться то они будут заменяться. В моем случае кличи могут повторятся.

Comment: думать видно не хотите...

    arr = [...]

#1
    res = dict()
    for rec in arr:
        fc = rec[0]
        tc = rec[1]
        if tc in res and fc in res[tc]:
            continue
        if fc not in res:
            res[fc] = []
        res[fc] += [tc]

#2

    res = []
    for rec in arr:
        fc = rec[0]
        tc = rec[1]
        wf = False
        for res_rec in res:
            rfc = res_rec[0]
            rtc = res_rec[1]
            if tc == rfc and fc == rtc:
                wf = True
                break
        if wf == True:
            continue
        res += [rec]

Comment: Можно сделать еще проще:

    result = []
    for record in arr:
        from_city = record[0]
        to_city = record[1]
        if [from_city, to_city] in result or [to_city, from_city] in result:
            continue
        result += [record]
    print result

с питоном толком не знаком, поэтому возможно для таких случаев существует более подходящее решение

второй пример, кстати, не совсем правильно работал, если существуют две одинаковые записи

Comment: Последний вариант хороший получился. Немного затупил в решении задачи...

Comment: Последний код можно немного оптимизировать:

    result = set()
    for from_city, to_city in arr:
        if not (to_city, from_city) in result:
            result.add((from_city, to_city))

Comment: Порядок не важен, данные нужны для построение дерево графов.

Comment: Немного переделанный код http://pastebin.com/41tjqtQr

Получаю результат:

   [('a', 'c', '27', '25')]

Нужно получить:

   [('a', 'c', '27', '25'),('a', 'b', '28'), ('c', 'd', '25')]

Как не найденные пересечение подставить?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на свой вопрос:

[Решение](http://pastebin.com/zzrEpqLs)

Comment: "This page is no longer available. It has either expired, been removed by its creator, or removed by one of the Pastebin staff.": наглядный пример того, почему не нужно давать ответ-ссылку.